# Uploading digital signature to folder and submitting to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have been trying to manage that the signature image gets submitted to upload to a folder and add to
the database at the same time but having a tough time. Everything is working except uploading the signature image to a folder and submitting it to the database with the same record.

I am using the digital signature from this jquery code : https://www.jqueryscript.net/mobile/Simpe-Mobile-Signature-Pad-with-jQuery-Html5-Canvas.html

Current example of what I have : http://dev.teqcube.com/signin-test/signin.php

This is for the 'New Visitor' Section

#### This is the form

```html
<form method="post" action="">

    <!-- VISITOR FIRST NAME -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="visitor_first_name" id="visitor_first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
    </div>

    <!-- VISITOR LAST NAME -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="visitor_last_name" id="visitor_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </div>

    <!-- VISITOR COMPANY NAME -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="visitor_company_name" id="visitor_company_name" placeholder="Company Name" required>
    </div>

    <!-- VISITING PURPOSE -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="custom-select form-control" name="visitor_visiting_purpose" id="visitor_visiting_purpose" style="width:100%;" required="required">
        <option value="" selected>Visiting Purpose</option>
        <option value="Visiting">Visiting</option>
        <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
        <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
        <option value="Maintanance">Maintanance</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!-- APARTMENT NUMBER -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="visitor_visiting_apartment_number" id="visitor_visiting_apartment_number" placeholder="Apartment Number" required>
    </div>

    <!-- FORM SUBMIT FOR NEW REGISTRATION -->
    <div class="submitBtnContainer">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#digitalSignatureModal" class="btn my-2 my-sm-0 submitTakePhoto"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>Signature</button>
      <button type="submit" name="sign_visitor_in" class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0 signoutVisitorFormOption1"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sign In</button>
    </div>


    <!-- #### MODAL TO APPLY DIGITAL SIGNATURE #### -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="digitalSignatureModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <!-- MODAL BODY LOGO -->
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="signinSuccessModalLogo">
              <img src="img/Excellent-visitor-signin-small.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- MODAL BODY CONTENT -->
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="modal-body" id="signinSuccessModalContent">

              <!-- DISPLAY IMAGE AFTER SIGNED -->
              <div id="signaturePad" data-role="content"></div>

              <!-- DIGITAL SIGNATURE SECTION -->
              <div  id="divPopUpSignContract">
                <div class="ui-content popUpHeight">
                  <div id="div_signcontract">

                    <!-- CANVAS TO DRAW SIGNATURE -->
                    <canvas id="canvas">Canvas is not supported</canvas>

                    <!-- SUBMIT SIGNATURE OR CLEAR -->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <!-- <input id="btnSubmitSign" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" value="Submit Signature" onclick="fun_submit()" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 15px;" /> -->
                      <input id="btnSubmitSign" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" value="Submit Signature" onclick="fun_submit()" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 15px;" />
                      <input id="btnClearSign" type="button" class="btn btn-warning commentbtn" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" value="Clear" onclick="init_Sign_Canvas()" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 15px;" />
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /MODAL BODY CONTENT -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #### MODAL TO APPLY DIGITAL SIGNATURE #### -->

</form>
```

#### This is the php code to add the info to the database.

I am getting an error with $visitor_signature. I have tried different methods but not succeeding.

```html
// ### SUBMIT SIGNIN FORM FOR NEW VISITOR REGISTRATION ###
if(isset($_POST['sign_visitor_in'])) {

  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');
  $currentTime = date("H:i:s");

  // *** RETREIVE SUBMITTED INFORMATION ON SUBMIT FOR NEW VISITOR REGISTRATION ***
  $visitor_first_name                   = $_POST['visitor_first_name'];
  $visitor_last_name                    = $_POST['visitor_last_name'];
  $visitor_company_name                 = $_POST['visitor_company_name'];
  $visitor_visiting_purpose             = $_POST['visitor_visiting_purpose'];
  $visitor_visiting_apartment_number    = $_POST['visitor_visiting_apartment_number'];
  //$visitor_visit_status               = $_POST['visitor_visit_status'];
  $visitor_signin_date                  = date("Y-m-d");
  $visitor_signin_time                  = date("H:i:s");
  $visitor_signout_date                 = date("H:i:s");
  $visitor_signout_time                 = date("H:i:s");

  $visitor_signature                    = $_FILES['visitor_signature']['name'];
  $visitor_signature_tmp                = $_FILES['visitor_signature']['tmp_name'];

  move_uploaded_file($visitor_signature_tmp, "img/sign-in-signatures/$visitor_signature");

  exit();
  // *** I added exit() for testing purpose and once it works I remove it.

  // *** ADD NEW VISITOR SIGNIN RECORD TO DATABASE ***
  $query = "INSERT INTO visitors(visitor_first_name, visitor_last_name, visitor_company_name, visitor_visiting_purpose,
    visitor_visiting_apartment_number, visitor_visit_status, visitor_signin_date, visitor_signin_time, visitor_signout_date, visitor_signout_time, visitor_signature)";

  $query .= "VALUES('{$visitor_first_name}', '{$visitor_last_name}', '{$visitor_company_name}',
  '{$visitor_visiting_purpose}', '{$visitor_visiting_apartment_number}', 'Signed In', '{$visitor_signin_date}', '{$visitor_signin_time}', '', '', '{$visitor_signature}')";

  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

  // *** GENERAL CONFIM QUERY ***
  if(!$result) {
    die("QUERY FAILED. " . mysqli_error($connection));
  }
}
```

#### The below code is part of the js file where the signature takes place

```html
function fun_submit() {
  if(isSign) {
    var canvas = $("#canvas").get(0);
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
    jQuery('#signaturePad').find('p').remove();
    jQuery('#signaturePad').find('img').remove();
    jQuery('#signaturePad').append(jQuery('<p>Your Signature:</p>'));
    jQuery('#signaturePad').append($('<img/ name="visitor_signature">').attr('src',imgData));


    // I BELIEVE THIS IS WHERE THE PROCESS HAPPENS TO UPLOAD THE IMAGE TO THE FOLDER
    // I HAVE BEEN TRYING WITH DIFFERENT CODES IN THIS SECTION BUT NOT SUCCEEDING

    closePopUp();
  } else {
    alert('Please sign');
  }
}
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should :

1. change your HTML code with adding a hidden field in your form, like this :
   `<input type=hidden name="visitor_signature" id="visitor_signature">`
2. change your JS code in the fun_submit() function with adding : `jQuery('#visitor_signature').val(imgData)`
3. and finally change your PHP code from :

```php
  $visitor_signature                    = $_FILES['visitor_signature']['name'];
  $visitor_signature_tmp                = $_FILES['visitor_signature']['tmp_name'];
  move_uploaded_file($visitor_signature_tmp, "img/sign-in-signatures/$visitor_signature");
```

to

```php
  $visitor_signature = $_POST['visitor_signature'];
 // we receive something like : data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAvcAAADICAYAAABszM7qAAAZc0lEQVR4Xu3da4hVVRsH8GVeS
 // we remove the "data:image/png;base64,"
  $visitor_signature = preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $visitor_signature);
  $visitor_signature = base64_decode($visitor_signature);
  file_put_contents("img/sign-in-signatures/visitor_signature.png",$visitor_signature);
```

as the signature image isn't anymore a uploaded file, but a base64 string put in the textfield "visitor_signature"

Comment: Hi Pierre, thank you for your reply, I have tried it but still getting : Notice: Undefined index: visitor_signature

Comment: @Dane, i've updated my answer with working code (tested in my computer)...it generates correctly the png signature image on the disk...

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for your time, I appreciate it.

I did as you pointed out to me and started getting an sql error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your SQL server version for the right syntax to use near

I then had a look around and added base64_encode before it inserts into the db and then it worked. Without the base64_decode the image won't open in the folder but without the encode afterwards it doesn't upload to the db. Code looks like this now :

```html
    $visitor_signature                    = $_POST['visitor_signature'];

     // we receive something like : data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAvcAAADICAYAAABszM7qAAAZc0lEQVR4Xu3da4hVVRsH8GVeS
     // we remove the "data:image/png;base64,"

    $visitor_signature                    = preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $visitor_signature);
    $visitor_signature                    = base64_decode($visitor_signature);

    file_put_contents("img/sign-in-signatures/" . $visitor_first_name . "_" . $visitor_last_name . "_signature_" . $visitor_company_name . ".png",$visitor_signature);

    $visitor_signature                    = base64_encode($visitor_signature);
```

Inside the db it still add a huge string but in the backend I am calling the image :

```html
// VISITOR SIGNATURE IMAGE
 echo "
 <td style='text-align:center;'>
    <img src='../img/sign-in-signatures/{$visitor_first_name}_{$visitor_last_name}_signature_{$visitor_company_name}.png' width='125px'>
 </td>";
```

Once again thank you for your time, I hope you have a great upcoming 2019.
Regards

Comment: Happy to have helped you! I wish you a happy new year 2019! :-)

Comment: Otherwise, I think you could avoid to store the entire base64 signature in db. You can create a unique non-guessable ID with timestamp+random, then you name the image signature with this timestamp. Finally, remains to you to store the image name in the database instead of storing the full image content...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will have a look at it tomorrow morning and see the outcome :)